# difference between characters online and on localhost

Tags: character-encoding

The question is ,I hope,simple for someone who knows about character encoding.
This is my site.

http://www.football-tennis-stats.com/index.php/stats/display/tennis

Online, the character set is wrong ,I get this weird Â,while on localhost everything is allright.

I know there is a lot of good reading to be done on this subject,but I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not seem to be any character encoding issue, just spurious data, namely bytes 0xC3 0x82, which represent the character Â when interpreted in UTF-8, which is the declared encoding. Otherwise, the content seems to be all ASCII, because the names are in “internationalized”, i.e. anglicized form, e.g. Djokovic instead of Đoković, Soderling instead of Söderling etc. With this data, it does not matter much how you declare its encoding, since ASCII characters mostly have the same representation anyway.

I have no idea where the bytes come from, but they seem to appear systematically between a comma and a space, so it’s apparently something in the code that generates the table.

Comment: I have yet to fix the problem.

Comment: I think your answer is a little to much for me to understand.In my site I do the following:I scrape some content from another website and save it into a mysql table.Then I process the data in some way and show it on my own site.The site which I scrape displays only english characters,(Soderling not Söderling).Viewing the table with php my admin it displays properly ,just like the content I scraped.When I display it on my localhost it shows up ok.When I display it on my live site,it shows up messed up. ex: Djokovic,Â Novak.

Comment: I think there is something I forgot to mention.There is a weird character &nbsp; (which coresponds to the white space after the comma).I guess this is what gets misinterpreted into Â .The problem is I tried to get rid of it when filtering the info from the scraped website BEFORE saving it into mysql and failed.I tried trim, and str_replace('&nbsp','',$someword) but it still gets saved into mysql table.

Comment: @alinache, you need to provide more information about the way (code) you use to produce the page. From the outside, we can only see the end result, the page that contains extraneous bytes. If the surname and the first name are stored separately and then used to generate the full name in the form “surname, firstname”, then the problem would appear to be in the pattern used for this

Comment: So maybe this is the question .How do I get rid of &nbsp;I read some threads from SO but they haven't helped.

Comment: I use character text/html; charset=utf-8 in the header.On my localhost mysql database I have MySQL connection collation:utf8_general_ci.I have the exact settings on my live site.

Comment: I solved it.For some strange reason when importing the whole database from local to live the Â popped up.When importing only the specific table ,it dissapeared.Thanks a lot for your advice anyway.Cheers.